# C function doesn't return correct value in another function

Tags: c, string, utf-8, struct

I have this problem. I have a function create_message that fill a structure

```
struct message {
struct header{
    char *protocol_version;         
    char *type;                     
    long int sequence_number;       
}header;                            
struct body
{
    int num_tag;                    
    char *tag_labels[LEN];          
    int num_attr_tag[LEN];          
    char *attr_labels[LEN][LEN];
    char *attr_values[LEN][LEN];    
    char *attr_types[LEN][LEN];         }body;                              
  };
```

The code of create_message is:

```
void create_message(struct message *msg, CharmsMsg *chmsg, char *protocol_version)
{
int i,j,n;
XTypes type = chmsg->type;
printf("Tipo %ld\n", chmsg->type);

msg->header.protocol_version = (char *) malloc(sizeof(char)*STRLEN);
msg->header.protocol_version = protocol_version;

msg->header.type = (char *) malloc(sizeof(char)*STRLEN);
msg->header.type = metadati[type].typemsg;

msg->header.sequence_number = chmsg->SeqNo;

msg->body.num_tag = metadati[type].num_tag;

n=0;
for(i=0;i<msg->body.num_tag;i++)        
{
    // assegno le etichette ai tag
    msg->body.tag_labels[i] = (char *) malloc(sizeof(char)*STRLEN);
    msg->body.tag_labels[i] = metadati[type].tag_labels[i];
    msg->body.num_attr_tag[i] = metadati[type].num_attr_tag[i];

    for(j=0;j<msg->body.num_attr_tag[i];j++)     
    {

        msg->body.attr_labels[i][j] = (char *) malloc(sizeof(char)*STRLEN);
        msg->body.attr_labels[i][j] = metadati[type].attr_labels[i][j];

        // assegno il valore dell'attributo j-esimo al tag i-esimo
        msg->body.attr_values[i][j] = (char *) malloc(sizeof(char)*STRLEN);
        msg->body.attr_values[i][j] = ((getDati[type])(chmsg->structCHARMS))[n++];
        printf("IN create_message: Contenuto buf[%d] %s\n",(i+j), msg->body.attr_values[i][j]);
        // assegno il tipo dell'attributo j-esimo al tag i-esimo
        msg->body.attr_types[i][j] = (char *) malloc(sizeof(char)*STRLEN);
        msg->body.attr_types[i][j] = metadati[type].attr_types[i][j];
    }
}
 }
```

Particurarly create_message call getDati[type] that is an array of pointer to function. A particular function inside this array is getRegisterMe, shown below

```
char **getRegisterMe(void *structCHARMS)
{
ClientData *client = (ClientData *)structCHARMS;
char *buf[3];
int i;

for(i=0; i< 3; i++)
    buf[i] = (char*)calloc(MAX_SEQ_LEN, sizeof(char));

//attributi del tag[0]:Cookie
sprintf(buf[0], "%d", client->cookie_value);
//attributi del tag[1]:Register
sprintf(buf[1], "%s", addrtostr(client->local_addr));
sprintf(buf[2], "%d", client->mode);

printf("IN getData buf[0]%s\n",buf[0]);
printf("IN getData buf[1]%s\n",buf[1]);
printf("IN getData buf[2]%s\n",buf[2]);

return (char **)buf;
}
```

When I launch the program I have that getRegisterMe doesn't fill correctly the elements of struct struct message. In fact I observe this:

```
IN getData buf[0]0
IN getData buf[1]127.0.0.1:53285
IN getData buf[2]3
IN create_message: Contenuto buf[0] ?   ?V׾??FR?
IN getData buf[0]0
IN getData buf[1]127.0.0.1:53285
IN getData buf[2]3
IN create_message: Contenuto buf[1] H??H???H??t?

IN getData buf[0]0
IN getData buf[1]127.0.0.1:53285
IN getData buf[2]3
IN create_message: Contenuto buf[2]
```

Why the value of char*buf printed in getRegisterMe doesn't match with the value printed of msg->body.attr_values?? Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 1):

Your function getRegisterMe returns a pointer to the local variable buf, which disappears when the function returns.

Answer (score 1):

There are several locations in your code where you are allocating memory, and assigning it to a pointer. Then, in the very next line, you are making your pointer point to somewhere different, so you've (a) leaked the memory you allocated, and (b) redirected your pointers to the passed-in data which you don't own.

```
msg->header.protocol_version = (char *) malloc(sizeof(char)*STRLEN);
msg->header.protocol_version = protocol_version;
```

You want to copy the data instead.

```
msg->header.protocol_version = (char *) malloc(sizeof(char)*STRLEN);
strncpy(msg->header.protocol_version, protocol_version, STRLEN);
```